# Android black screen in app

Tags: android

I have an android application with QR Code scan. Everything works fine until I installed GMD Hide Bar.

The screen will turn completely black after I successfully scan QR Code. But my app continues to run in black screen since I can hear the sound. I have to click the power button on my device twice (to turn off the screen once and turn it on again), then I can see the screen again.

Since they works individually so I'm not sure what cause this. Here is the code when the QR Code scanner scans a code and quit, for which is the moment when the screen turns black.

```
private final Handler  mUnityHandler   = new Handler() {
   @Override
   public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
   try {
      Class<UnityPlayer> c = com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.class;
      Method method = c.getMethod("UnitySendMessage", new Class[] { String.class, String.class, String.class });
      method.invoke(null, "CodeScannerBridge", "onScannerMessage", mDataStr); // reveiver null
      // because
      // UnitySendMessage
      // is
      // static
   } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return;
   } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return;
   }

   finish();
}
```

Any idea?

**EDIT** It doesnt happen 100% of the time, but often. And I have another function:

```
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            finish();
        }
    }, 10000);
```

I tested for this. It will turn black screen sometimes too.